# Rate of evaporation of water vs temperature. Where can I find data?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, water, evaporation, data

**The story**

If there is an easily understandable problem that fascinates me compare to apparently how hard it is to model and solve accurately, and how little it has been studied, the time to cool down my cup of tea taking into account the evaporation of water comes up first in my mind.

I did a simple experiment: cool down water in my cup, once with a lid on top of it and once without. The results are unequivocal. It takes (for my cup) twice as much time to cool it down when the lid is on (and this agrees my theoretical heat balance up to 5%).

I would like then to take into account the evaporation of water as it cools down. But so far I haven't found great literature on the subject when I thought for such a little question there would be a huge mound of it.

---

**What I have found so far**

I found [this article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.langmuir.7b00616) that gives the rate of evaporation of water at low pressure (up to 900 Pa). What is cool is that they derive the equations to solve the problem but I don't know how to implement them, nor what a tensor is and I would prefer using a correlation-based rate of evaporation as a function of temperature determined with the least square methods to correlate data to an equation model. And even for that, I don't find anything but I may have not searched correctly. It would be great to get data from 20 °C up to almost boiling water.

Comment: Why not measure *weight v. temperature* over time for a well-insulated cup/mug filled with (initially) hot water?

Comment: @Gert I would have to buy a precise balance which requires the use of a small cup otherwise the mass of the cup itself may be too much for the range of the balance. I don't have any good apparatus to do such a thing and working in the industry where evaporation is such as thing I find it mind-blowing that such precise experiment has never been done.

Comment: See Mass Tranfer Operations by Treybel.

Comment: A $200\pm0.01\mathrm{g}$ is very cheap. Use a small ramekin, plastic preferably.

Comment: Is your goal to calculate temperature of the tea vs. time?  If so, is the calculation to be done for one particular cup that is filled to the same level every time?  What I'm getting at: if you want a correlation of temperature vs. time, it would be much more straight-forward to directly measure that variable instead of looking for a way to determine evaporation rate vs. time and then using some type of correlation to calculate temperature vs. time.

Comment: @DavidWhite the goal would be to get a model that could be used for anything that requires those data. I am just quite amazed there is no 1st approximation model that would give some good results as we have for heat transfer. It would be nice to get some sort of coefficient k so we could do $dm/dt = -k \times \Delta T$ but apparently, that's not something easy to transpose from heat transfer. And would be nice to transpose for other liquids as well. The cup of tea is just a pretext.

Comment: @ParaH2, the heat transfer correlations are empirical for a reason.  Conduction, convection, and radiative heat transfer are normally all occurring at the same time, even though people normally focus on only one of the heat transfer phenomena at a time.  In addition, convection often involves turbulence, which is one of the great unsolved problems in physics.  Even though you are looking for a simple equation or correlation for your "tea cup" problem, the actual physics of that situation are anything but simple.

Comment: @DavidWhite sure it is a hard problem even for heat transfer. But that does not answer my point at all. There is lots of literature on heat transfer and even for my cup of tea, I am able to use correlations found in the Perry's with great accuracy. Why don't we have such things for mass transfer? Even with correlation, it's actually rather easy to take into consideration conduction, convection and radiative heat transfer.

Comment: @ParaH2, your problem is a combination of heat transfer and mass transfer.

Comment: @DavidWhite I know. Where am I not clear? The heat transfer part is well documented. Now I need the mass transfer documentation.

Comment: @ParaH2, I have a chemical engineering background, which is in the area that your question is, and I have NEVER seen research that combines heat transfer and mass transfer at the same time.  If you find such research, I would be interested in seeing a link to it.

Comment: @DavidWhite I am too (junior tho I don't like the term). And I have never too. Which is mostly why I posted the question here :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one source  that provides a simple relationship that may be accurate enough for your purposes:
https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=1440

The text Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot has correlations for mass transfer, including evaporation.